# Does every manifold with boundary admit a flat metric?

Tags: riemannian-geometry

There are several obstructions for a closed manifold $M$ admit a flat metric. for example Cartan-Hadamard Theorem implies the universal cover of $M$ must be $\mathbb R^n$. So if the manifold $M$ is allowed to have nonempty boundary and we do not put any restrictions on the boundary(say we do not ask it to be convex). Then can we say something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should explain what you mean by a flat metric is there is nonempty boundary. Whatever definition you have in mind, it should imply the existence of a flat metric on the interior of your manifold. You should also assume that the manifold is connected. For connected **oriented** manifolds of dimension $n\le 3$ there are no obstructions since every such manifold admits an immersion in $R^n$.

However, starting with dimension $n\ge 4$ there are obstructions. The simplest one is the following. Suppose that your manifold $M$ is also simply-connected. Then the existence of a flat metric on the interior of $M$ implies that $M$ admits an (isometric) immersion in $R^n$. This, in turn, implies that $M$ is parallelizable. (Actually, an open $n$-manifold is parallelizable if and only if it admits an immersion in $R^n$.) Now, take your favorite simply-connected non-parallelizable $n$-manifold with nonempty boundary, for instance, let $M$ be the complement to an open ball in $CP^2$. (It is not parallelizable because $CP^2$ is not a spin-manifold.) The interior of this manifold will not have a flat metric.